# How to remove unwanted padding/space added on my email marketing divider line in Outlook client

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am using this divider line for an email marketing campaign, and my friend (Outlook client) is adding additional space below the divider. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
<table class="wrapper" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><table class="container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" bgcolor="#fdfdfd" width="700" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" class="px-sm-20"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
              <tr>
                <th width="50" align="center" class="hide-sm" style="font-size:1px; line-height: 1px;">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="col" width="600" align="left" ><table class="full-width-sm" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="divider" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 20px;"><div style="background: #5C5C5C; height: 1px; line-height: 1px;">‌</div></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table></th>
                <th width="50" align="center" class="hide-sm" style="font-family: 'Ambit', Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px; line-height: 20pt;">&nbsp;</th>
              </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have mso-line-height-rule: exactly; around the divider class in the css.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook for Windows has a default font-size and line-height.

On the div you deal with the line-height but not the font-size, so you need `font-size:1px` too.